# Different /bin/bash shells for admin and non-admin users?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, bash, ssh

**QUICK NOTE**: I'm not sure if its necessary if I need to mention this but I'm running a chroot environment inside my /home directory

So I wasn't sure how to really google search this. I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate.

### Problem 1:

I'm running Ubuntu-server 14.04 and I'm able to successfully connect to ssh. However, I notice that the prefixes for a admin user and a non admin user is different.

Nebulous is the admin account (the account created for me during system install).

```
Using username "nebulous".
Authenticating with public key "" from agent
nebulous@Nebulous-Linux:~$
```

Appmanager is the non admin account.

```
Using username "appmanager".
Authenticating with public key "" from agent
-bash-4.3$
```

Prefixes to compare are:

- nebulous@Nebulous-Linux:~$
- -bash-4.3$

If both users are set to use /bin/bash:

```
nebulous:x:1000:1000:nebulous,,,:/home/nebulous:/bin/bash
appmanager:x:1002:1001:,,,,:/:/bin/bash
```

Why are the prefixes different?

This also seems to cause a problem with aliases.

### Problem 2:

If I login with nebulous, then `su appmanager`, and execute an alias, it works properly.
However, if I were to login with a non-admin account and try to execute an alias, it doesnt recognize the same alias

Admin Terminal:

```
appmanager@Nebulous-Linux:/home/appmanager$ helloworld
Hello, World!
```

Non-Admin Terminal:

```
-bash-4.3$ helloworld
-bash: helloworld: command not found
```

What causes the shell to not recognize the alias?

Comment: There is no `/home/appmanager` in chroot `/home`. Either modify the home directory in the `/etc/passwd` or in the `ssh` after chroot.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask *one question*, so you can receive *one answer*.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  **;-)** So please, split up your question into multiple questions.  (It's not like we charge you here by the number of questions you create you know!)  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my both my problems.

All that's needed is to `source path/to/user/.bashrc`

I get a proper prefix:

```
appmanager@Nebulous-Linux:/$
```

and my aliases also work.

```
appmanager@Nebulous-Linux:/$ helloworld
Hello, World!
```

I also apologize for misuse of the AskUbuntu Q&A site. Thanks for the tip @Fabby